# Single row column bar chart plotly python

Tags: python, plotly-python

When I have a multiple rows in a column it is able to plot properly other wise it was not able to plot properly.

Please find below code

```py
fig = px.bar(result, x = attributeName, y = "GapCount",text="GapCount",template="simple_white")
            fig.update_traces(marker_color='rgb(158,202,225)', marker_line_color='rgb(8,48,107)',
                  marker_line_width=1.5, opacity=0.6,textposition='auto')
```

Please find below charts

[image]

[image]

I wanted to have a single bar when single row is available as in second chart.

Comment: I can not reproduce this error. Can you show us how you defined the variables "result" and "attirbuteName"?

Comment: Got resolved as it was getting string value in above graph